# What does "即オチ" mean?

Tags: slang, twitter

Context:
I follow a Japanese artist on Pixiv who posts short original manga periodically.
Recently he posted a new chapter of his manga ahead of his posted schedule announced on his Twitter, I read the new chapter and replied "早い！" thought I convey the meaning "wow you posted this early!" I know I could have phrased it better but I was too excited and still quite new in Japanese (N4).
The original creator replied to my comment with "即オチ" I then did a little research trying to understand what he meant but I couldn't... Seems like an internet slang.
Can anyone explain the meaning of this slang?

Comment: Oh... I think I dug up your original tweet and naruto's answer seems mostly correct. It'd be something like "insta-surrender".

Comment: haha you actually found it? Also I am not sure how you get the phrase "insta-surrender"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

即 means "instant" or "immediate". オチ is from 落ちる, and has two major meanings:

1. punchline (of a joke), final joke (of a comedy performance), final result (of a story)
2. falling in love, being hooked, being addicted

So 即【そく】オチ refers to a type of manga where the funniest part comes near the very beginning, or a manga that is simply very short, or a manga where someone falls in love immediately. Either way, I think the author thought your comment (早い!) referred to the content or length of the manga rather than the post date. Does the posted manga fit this description?

Comment: Ohh interesting, in that case, the author might actually think I was referring to the content of the manga. However, I am still unsure, what would the English equivalent to this?

Comment: @jack888 Sorry, I don't even know if there is an equivalent.